# How would you design a generic layer for OpenGL windowing that does not care how the program underneath actually looks like?

Tags: c++, design, opengl

The kind of OpenGL windowing that I refer to is like GLFW, GLUT, SDL, etc.

Imagine three C++ programs: (ignore syntax)

Game A:

```
class Game
    resize()
    keyEvent()
```

Game B:

```
resize()
keyEvent()
```

Game C:

```
class Key
    event()
class Display
    resize()
```

In A, everything is in one class, in B nothing is in a class, and in C the two events have their own classes. Another that is not shown is subclassing a provided 'Game' class that has predefined functions overloaded.

I would like any reasonable means that can allow the main library to delegate out to each of these three cases. The solution should not require separate storage of a 'this' parameter.

I have thought of a couple of ideas, one is a way of mapping the function in a functor. Another was lambdas. Lambdas are not okay, because they are not widely implemented yet. (Compilers of choice are VC 2010, gcc (latest stable), and Apple's clang).

Any new C++ 2011 features that are widely implemented are reasonable thoughts.

A gentleman at the local university suggested something similar to the functor, but I cannot remember the function he was talking about.

Comment: A. is a god-object and B. will run into troubles with multiple windows and threading.

Comment: Quite right. Each one has their place. I would use B definitely in a little program that was to be quick to make. In the slightly larger case, A is what I am using for my current project. It should be noted that B is how GLUT and GLFW work.

Comment: What is the reason for not wanting to store a 'this' parameter?  Have you looked at the Adapter design pattern?

Comment: I guess that it is impossible to create a code that encapsulates all the data in a way that you can have absolute no assumptions about how the things work. One thing of another must be known about the functionality being provided.

Comment: Belongs on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

> I have thought of a couple of ideas, one is a way of mapping the
>   function in a functor.

`std::function` -> problem solved. If you have a compiler that doesn't support `std::function`, then use `boost::function`. Lambdas have nothing to do with it- if you're using a compiler that supports them then you can do it, else use `boost::bind`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear what your true intention is. However, describing you based on some assumptions.

Before you think of a methods - you need to define the abstraction of the core objects - such as Windows, surfaces, canvas and the device layer which would do the rendering. I believe the inputs (such as key board and mouse) would be objects as well. A good deal of work is to represent hardware - and while many are attempting to do it, it is not that universal thing.

If you are wanting to create GUI type framework than there will be whole object hierarchies like buttons and form elements etc. If you intend to do this for the class of rendering (what openGL actually aims to) you have higher level representations of Square and Triangles and how do draw Textures on them!

Once, you sort this out you need to define their behavior of inputs and outputs they will take and define which other objects they will deal with using the other API.